# how do i get a discord message and input it into the python terminal

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to find a useful code method to receive discord message data to input to my keyboard so that discord could control my pc for something like fun stuff or for the Redacted of it.

list of what I am using
pip latest software
python 3
discord.py

Comment: You'd just listen for a specific message as usual, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve? What about `on_message(message): ...` doesn't work for you?

Comment: well i got an error trying to use `on_message(message):` the error is `illegal target for annotation (<unknown>, line 8)`

Comment: Can you update your question with what you've tried so far in terms of handling messages? Also could you clarify what you want to achieve in terms of "control my pc"? Do you want it to send an email, play a sound file, ...?

Comment: Could you please include a snippet of relevant code? Maybe the part that's causing the error? It could help us help you :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
```

Comment: this is the error trying to run the code 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\PlayingWithDiscord\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    @client.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument:coro'